# Unity Gaming Service - How to truly delete a player account

Tags: unity-game-engine, cloud

I am trying to delete the player account, which somewhat work.

As there is, what seems, an automatic anonymous login after

```
await AuthenticationService.Instance.DeleteAccountAsync();
```

I am testing to delete that as well without signing in.

Not very successful, anyone that can give some light how to manage delete of a player account in this point of view?

Comment: `Deletes the currently signed in player permanently.` ... wouldn't it be a bit risky to allow an account to be deleted without requiring login ..?

Comment: No that is not what I am trying to accomplish. What I try to do is to delete the account that is logged in then stop UGS to create/login a new anonymous, which seems to be default. However I will put in a bool and stop the second login and see if that works.